# Is an Explosion Proof Circuit Breaker Panel Required at a Gas Station?

Tags: electrical-engineering, safety, gas

Check the attached photo of a gasoline station.

[image: Gas Station]

The two panel boxes at the center of the photo (in the corner of the station) are standard panels (IP-67), which enclose standard circuit breakers for the main gas pumps of the station.

They are less than 7 linear meters on separation.

I would like to ask you, if you have experience on electrical EX-proof facilities:

**Is there any mistake here? Or is everything right according to the EX-proof codes?**

Comment: It would be helpful for you to add what it is that you think might be wrong or out of code.

Comment: motor vehicles are never ex-proof, so the gas station can't be an ex-zone (has to be built so that it isnt). You still shouldnt smoke there.

Comment: You have a point with that. But you must define Class I Division I and Division II areas at gas stations. I have concern by using those standard panels there, just as if it were any standard industrial zone.

Comment: What is your jurisdiction/governing code?

Comment: Better lets talk on terms of IEC, NEC, NFPA or other, whatever you have working experience on.

Answer (score 2):

I see nothing in your picture to indicate that the circuit breakers need to be explosion proof.  They don't appear to be in a zone 0 location, nor would I expect that any explosion proof volume would extend thru the conduit to the circuit breakers.  That just doesn't make sense.

Also, cars aren't zone 0 rated in the first place, and neither are all kinds of things you are allowed to have in the car and on your person while filling up at a gas station.  The protection is between the gasoline and where you can get at it, not in the zone around the pump.

Your whole concept doesn't make sense.

Comment: Existing an undergroung gasoline vessel indeed force me to define Hazardous Area Classification as per NEC or NFPA, and calculation ventilations and so because of vents and fuel connections. Though i am requesting your experience on this particular situation. For me, it am not fine by looking that standard panel with standard breakers close (or inside?) to a Zone 2 area.....